# Filter several file names for FileDialog

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that opens up a VBA fileDialog window that allows me to select several files and returns those I selected.

In the folder where it runs there are several other files and I need to make it as monkey-proof as possible for the users, so I want to set a filter for the filenames that they can open.

Up to now, there was only one structure for the file names: "xxxxx_Orders_xxxx.xls", and I was doing this with `FileDialog.InitialFileName`. But now I have two types of files: "xxxxx_Orders_xxxx.xls" and "xxxxx_Registrations_xxxx.xls" and I can't get the file dialog window to show me only those types of files in the folder.

I have tried with `FileDialog.InitialFileName = "*Orders*|*Registrations*"` but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help? Here's the code that I have for getting the files:

```
Function getFiles(Optional nameFilter As String = "", Optional windowTitle As String = "", Optional multiSelect As Boolean = True, Optional maxSelected As Integer = 10000) As FileDialogSelectedItems
' Prompts the user to choose one or more files and returns the selected files
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim wbPath As String

   If windowTitle = "" Then windowTitle = "Select one or more files to process"
   
showWindow:
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
      .Filters.Clear
      .Title = windowTitle
      .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" ' Open current directory by default
      .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xl*;*.xm*"
      .AllowMultiSelect = multiSelect
      .InitialFileName = nameFilter ' <--- NAME FILTER
      If .show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
         wbPath = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
                
      'If inArray(.SelectedItems, ThisWorkbook.FullName) <> -1 Then finishProgram ("You can't select this Workbook.")
      
      Set getFiles = .SelectedItems
   End With
   
   Select Case getFiles.count
      Case 0:  End
      Case Is > maxSelected: GoTo showWindow
      Case Else: ' Continue
   End Select
   
   'If wbPath = "" Then End  'if no file chosen, end the program 
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible using the filepicker in that way. But you could perhaps use `Dir` to build a list of acceptable files and display them in a userform you make yourself which the user could then MultiSelect from a ComboBox..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different file picker in Excel. It is a bit different, but it might help you.
Try something like this:

```
ChDrive "c:"
ChDir "c:\Folder\Folder\"
SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Orders, *order*.xl*, Registrations, *registrations*.xl*", 1, , , True)
```

The `ChDrive` and `ChDir` are needed to navigate to the correct folder and the correct drive.